# How to select words that has no definitions

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

I have the following tables:

**table: words**

```
    id word
    1  a
    2  b
    3  c ... so on
```

**table: definitions**

```
 id wid land definition
 1  1   en   the first letter of the Roman alphabet
 2  1   en   the blood group "A"
 3  1   my   Definition of 'a' in Malaysia
 4  1   sg   Definition of 'a' in Singapore
 5  2   en   the second letter....
 6  2   en   the blood group "B"
 7  2   my   Definition of 'b' in Malaysia
 8  2   sg   Definition of 'b' in Singapore
 .... and so on.
```

My goal is to find a word that does not have a definition in a specific language, so I can add a definition. In this case, I want to pull up the word 'c'.

So when I try:

```
"SELECT word FROM words, definition WHERE words.id = wid AND lang != 'my'
```

I get all words: 'a', 'b', and 'c'.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry, my question was not so clear! In my above example, the word 'c' might have definitions in other languages. So my question is to select words that do not have definitions in specific language.

Comment: It gave me the words that has definition in 'my' language even though I tried with where language != 'my'. Sorry, I struggle with markups, here.

Comment: @Lian In the future, when you have a mysql question, please provide a sqlfiddle link with all the necessary db tables dumped in.  This allows volunteers to swiftly answer your question with a high degree of confidence and accuracy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a subquery here to select all words that are in your targeted language. Then do a `not` so it gives you all words not in that language.

```
SELECT id, word 
FROM words 
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT wid FROM definitions WHERE land ='my')
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2d146/3/0

Comment: Not `language`, rather `land`.  Don't you use capitalized keywords? I find sql easier to read that way.

Comment: Thanks, missed that (maybe thats why original comment didnt work, doh). No, I don't usually capitalize keywords, it is easier to read though.